# Error during launch of an Android emulator

Tags: android, react-native, npm

I don't understand why I have this problem when I launch the emulator.

```
warning: the transform cache was reset.
Loading dependency graph, done.
error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `react` from `/Users/myname/Sites/Project/App.js`: Module `react` does not exist in the Haste module map

This might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968
To resolve try the following:
  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
  3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.
  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.
```

I start the server with `npm start -- --reset-cache` command but it doesn't work. And also I tried to follow the above instruction.
How can I do?

I don't believe that it is a code problem, I update my Android Studio and install a component (react native elements) and now it doesn't work anymore.
Some help?

Comment: May be you are looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43304012/i-am-getting-unable-to-resolve-module-react)

Comment: @BhavikParmar I tried these solutions but they don't work :/

Comment: I use the commands in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/jarretmoses/c2e4786fd342b3444f3bc6beff32098d) for clearing the cache. Just remember to shut down your bundler as well.

Comment: @Andrew I should paste all the code?

Comment: No, you only need to choose one, based on your requirements. If you are using windows then probably the last one, mac then probably the second last one.

Comment: @Andrew nothing change :(

Comment: try installing watchman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by installing in the application folder:

```
npm install react
```